# AWS CORS Enabling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to enable CORS on Amazon

Here is my rule for the `All Buckets/elsticbeans-west-12345`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So as I understand it, it should allow full access to the application from any website, however the only thing that work is GET and when I'm sending a different request it shows:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote
resource at pagelink. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain
or enabling CORS.
```

Can someone explain me what is possibly wrong with my rule.